# useStripe does not return all API methods

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, next.js

I'm currently working on refactoring old code that uses the Stripe API.

I'm working with nextjs and the useStripe hook, however in the old code (in the backend), the:

`const stripeApi = new Stripe(config);`

instance was able to access methods such as:

`stripeApi.customers.list(options)`

Right now I am successfully calling the hook:

`const stripe = useStripe();`

It returns many usable methods but it does not allow me to access customers for example, am I initiating the instance in the wrong way, are they different instances?

Answer (score 1):

`useStripe` is something from the [client-side Stripe.js library](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#usestripe-hook), but things related to customers require the server-side [stripe-node library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node).